# How to loop over webpages when using selenium to scrape specific information?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Assuming I want to loop over a list of URLs and scrape some information utilizing selenium, I am trying to switch between pages without any issue so that by the end of each loop, I have created a PNG file consisting of a word cloud based on the quotes of different figures. Attached is the code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from WordCloudCreator import WordCloudGeneration

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
base_url_1, base_url_2 = 'https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/', '-quotes'
figures = {1: 'george-washington', 2: 'thomas-jefferson', 3: 'abraham-lincoln', 4: 'john-kennedy', 5: 'george-h-w-bush', 6: 'barack-obama', 7: 'donald-trump', 8: 'joe-biden', 9: 'martin-luther-king-jr'}
urls = [base_url_1+figure+base_url_2 for figure in list(figures.values())]


def wordCouldCreator(input_text, figure_name):
    wordcloud_generator = WordCloudGeneration()
    wordcloud_generator.create_word_cloud(input_text, figure_name)


for fitureId, figure, url in zip(list(figures.keys()), list(figures.values()), urls):
    browser.get(url)
    window_before = browser.window_handles[fitureId-1]
    elementExistence = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@title="view quote"]'))
    quotes = [x.text for x in wait.until(elementExistence) if len(x.text) > 5]
    figureQuote = ' '.join(quotes)
    wordCouldCreator(figureQuote, fitureId)
    window_after = browser.window_handles[fitureId]
    browser.switch_to.window(window_after)
    browser.switch_to.window(window_before)
```

However, the loop cannot proceed beyond the first increment. It basically stops after creating the first figure with an exiting error message:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!

DevTools listening on ws://******/devtools/browser/******
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\WebScraper\WebScraper.py", line 56, in <module>
    window_after = browser.window_handles[fitureId]
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to resolve the problem was to move some of the lines into the for loop and get rid of some others: (probably there is a more clever way I am not aware of)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from WordCloudCreator import WordCloudGeneration

base_url_1, base_url_2 = 'https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/', '-quotes'
figures = {1: 'george-washington', 2: 'thomas-jefferson', 3: 'abraham-lincoln', 4: 'john-kennedy', 5: 'george-h-w-bush', 6: 'barack-obama', 7: 'donald-trump', 8: 'joe-biden', 9: 'martin-luther-king-jr'}
urls = [base_url_1+figure+base_url_2 for figure in list(figures.values())]


def wordCouldCreator(input_text, figure_name):
    wordcloud_generator = WordCloudGeneration()
    wordcloud_generator.create_word_cloud(input_text, figure_name)


for fitureId, figure, url in zip(list(figures.keys()), list(figures.values()), urls):
    service = Service()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
    browser.get(url)
    elementExistence = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@title="view quote"]'))
    quotes = [x.text for x in wait.until(elementExistence) if len(x.text) > 5]
    figureQuote = ' '.join(quotes)
    wordCouldCreator(figureQuote, fitureId)
    browser.close()
```